# Random Option In Django Drop Down Form

Tags: python, django, forms, models, dropdown

I've been picking my brain trying to figure this out and so now I turn to the community for help.

I'm using models to create a form in Django and I want to add a Random option to a few of the drop-down choices.

Here is a general idea of what I'm working with:

models.py

```
Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=creation_choices.GENDERS)
    race = models.CharField(max_length=500,choices=creation_choices.RACE)
```

creation_choices.py

```
GENDERS = (
    ('male',"Male"),
    ("female","Female"),
    ("unknown","Unknown"),
)
RACE = (
    ('human','Human'),
    ('elf','Elf'),
    ('dwarf','Dwarf'),
)
```

What I am trying to do is add a way for users to select Random and it returns one of the other values. I tried a lot of different methods but most returned an error. When I created a function with random.choice() and pushed that through it seemed to work, but for some reason always returned the same value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should try the `choices` argument to the FormField instead of the ModelField, it is more versatile and accepts a callable to generate the choices dynamically.

Comment: @KlausD. is right. Add a "random" option to the choices of the corresponding form field, and process that extra option in the `clean_fieldname` method of the form.

Answer (score 0):

add `(None,'Random')` to choice sets and on the model-fields in question declare 
`default=select_random_gender` and `default=select_random_race` as well as `blank=False, null=False`.

declare these functions:

```python
def select_random_gender():
    selection = random.choice(GENDERS)[0]
    return selection if selection else select_random_gender()

def select_random_race():
    selection = random.choice(RACE)[0]
    return selection if selection else select_random_race()
```